# How can I pin point a certain string and then navigate to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a Chrome extension which saves a keyword locally.

I would like to use this information in order to search a webpage for this keyword (as a string). When an instance of the keyword is found I want to follow the link associated with it.

I am assuming there will only ever be a single match for the keyword and that the keyword will always be associated with a href link.

For instance the code within the HTML page looks like this

```
<a href="/shop/" class="name-link">Cargo Pant</a>
```

**Question**
How can I use the keyword `"Cargo Pant"` to find this element and navigate to the  href link in this element.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Select all the links, loop over, match text, read attribute, navigate.

Comment: Is using jQuery an option or does it need to be pure native JavaScript?

Comment: What do you want to have happen if more than one match is in the page? Navigate to the first one found I assume? Or something else?

Comment: @jwpfox the keyword will be something where there is only one instance of it in the page this will be the title of a product, once it has found this I would like it to follow the link associated with the text. Hope this helps

Comment: And the question about jQuery?

Comment: @jwpfox yes jQuery is an option, sorry completely forgot about that, I have very little knowledge in these languages thanks for being patient

Comment: @epascarello how would I go about doing this? saving the links from an external site is my problem currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** the most elegant answer but it steps you through a lot of examples that I hope will help you to understand what we are doing at each stage.

You can improve this a lot by using better jQuery selectors and the like but they all get harder to understand for a beginner so I hope this long-winded, clumsy, approach is better for understanding the steps in the thinking process and then you can trim it down as you understand what is happening at each step and then research how to make it better.

```
<html>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="http://google.com.au" class="name-link">Utility Kilt</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://google.com.au" class="name-link">Cargo Pant</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://google.com.au" class="name-link">Dress Pant</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      'use strict';
      var keyword = 'Cargo Pant',
          matches = $('a');
      alert('found this many anchor tags = ' + matches.length);
      matches.each(function(){
        alert('text in this element = ' + this.text);
        if (this.text === keyword) {
          alert('text in this element = ' + this.text +
            ' matches this keyword = ' + keyword);
          alert('about to navigate to = ' + this.href);
          location.href = this.href;
          return false;
        } else {
            alert('text in this element = ' + this.text +
              ' does NOT match this keyword = ' + keyword);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much I will try this out when I next get chance and let you know own if it works for what I'm trying to do, much appreciated